# Rails 3 Three Models Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't seem to get this right for some reason, though it sounds simple :/

I have three models :

```
User(id,name,email)
Skill(id,name,description)
UserSkill(user_id,skill_id,level)
```

How can i get all skills of a certain user, whether he or she has discovered them or not ?

For example, 3 skills (walk, talk, write). 3 users (John, Mary, Jack).

If Mary walks and writes, how can i get it back as a result like :

```
Mary => {Skill: walk(includes UserSkill), Skill : talk, Skill : write(includes UserSkill) }
```

You get the idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User

  def skill_list
    Skill.all(
      :select =>"skills.*, A.user_id AS user_id",
      :joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN user_skills A 
                 ON A.skill_id = skills.id 
                  AND A.user_id = #{id}").map do |skill|
      skill.name + (skill.user_id.nil? ? "" : "(*)")
    end
  end

end
```

Now

```
user = User.find_by_name("Mary")
user.skill_list
```

Will print:

```
[
  walk(*),
  talk,
  write(*)
]
```

Comment: Edited the answer take a look.

Comment: unluckily it still gives [] :(

Comment: I tried this by creating a project with the suggested models and it works for me. I had to change the `empty?` to check to `nil?` check. I had made two edits. Can you try the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to set something up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :skills, :through => :user_skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, :through => :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

then you can do:

```
my_user.skills # returns all Skill records assigned to the user
my_user.user_skills.includes(:skill) # this allows you to access :level in addition to Skill attributes
```

So the way to get both skills and user_skills is to use the :user_skills association. Basic has_many :through. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're wondering how to create the UserSkill records, there are a few ways. One good way is to call create off the association: `my_user.user_skills.create(:skill => the_skill, :level => the_level)`

Comment: the problem is that my_user.user_skills.includes(:skill) only gets skill if user has user_skill. I want to get skill, even if user does not have it.

Comment: Take a look at my example result set. It includes all skills and user_skill if it applies.

Comment: something like `Skill.includes(:user_skills).where(:user_skills => {:id => my_user.id})`

Comment: still []. I think there should be a join condition :/

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.first
user.user_skills.all.map(&:skills)
```

Comment: this does not return the skills irb(main):011:0> user.user_skills.includes(:skills).where(:user_id=>user.id).all.map(&:skills)
=> []

Comment: looks like there is no skills for that user